# "cleos set contract" vs "cleos set code" and "cleos set abi"

Tags: cleos

I have a beginner question:

What is the difference between:

`cleos set contract`

and

`cleos set code` with `cleos set abi`

looks like they are the same and basically set contract combines setting the code and abi in one go.

For example if I do:

```
cleos set contract hello ./hello hello.wasm hello.abi -p hello@active
```

is equal to:

```
cleos set code hello hello.wasm
cleos set abi hello hello.abi
```

What are the differences?

From quick research looks like we can use only `cleos set code` and we don't need to call `cleos set abi` when the abi is the same, so it is one less operation, but I though `cleos set contract` should also skip that internally?

Any noticeable differences?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are indeed right. Cleos *set contract* is nothing else than *set code* and *set abi* combined into a single command. And it skips set abi if the abi is the same as the one currently set.